# Angular routing does not change navigation on Long base64 URL string

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, angular-routerlink, base64url

I have the problem that my angular nav page is not "updating" when I click on links that look quite similar in path, they just differ in a long base64 string at the end that contains saved user profile data. Depending on the data that is saved, the string can be shorter or longer (e.g 324 characters long).
the URL look like:

```
localhost:4200//component/JTdCJTIybG9jYXRpb24lMjIlM0ElMjJjb250cmFjdCUyMiUyQyUyMnNlYXJjaFBhcmFtZXRlcnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJwYWdlU2l6ZSUyMiUzQTEwJTJDJTIycGFnZSUyMiUzQTElN0QlMkMlMjJsaXN0SGlkZGVuQ29scyUyMiUzQSU3QiUyMmNvbnRyYWN0JTIyJTNBJTVCJTIyY29udHJhY3RJZCUyMiUyQyUyMmNvbnRyYWN0Q3VzdG9tZXJUeXBlJTIyJTJDJTIyY29udHJhY3RDcmVhdGlvblR5cGUlMjIlNUQlKJASDKJA=
```

my link looks like `<a [routerLink]="aboveURL" />` and if I have multiple similar with just the ending base64 string different, then apparently Angular either does not change the page navigation OR it just does not parse the correct data out of the base64.
But I don't think later is the case, because if I navigate to an entirely different page and back then it loads normally...

Comment: Have you tried to add it as a parameter instead and then subscribing to the paramMap on the route, then you should be able to get the data and update the routes correctly.

Comment: Thank I will try that.